# Calculate Average delivery dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate an average of delivery dates from the time of arrival to the time of delivery start,

[ETA date, VS DELIVERY START](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTd8b.png)

As some deliveries have not started, and the values are blank I cannot seem to get the average for [Line chart no info for departments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsJUU.png)

I have tried the below formula but I cannot get to the result I want.

[AVERAGEX & DATEDIFF FORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW0BU.png)

I am struggling to find a solution

Thanks in advance

I have tried
AVERAGEX(DATEDIFF between my delivery start date and the ETA (estimated time of arrival)

But as there are blank values I cannot get averages for some of my departments

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. With this data

[image]

and this measure

```
Avg Days = 
AVERAGEX(
    'Table',
    DATEDIFF('Table'[ETA], 'Table'[DELIVERY START], DAY)
)
```

you'll get this result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter, this is the exact formula I have, It does not work. The formula is taking in consideration the blanks or 0 to make an average. I need to divide by the cells that contain the value of the date difference to get the proper average

Comment: If the formula doesn't work for you, your date columns probably don't have **date** data type, but **text**? [Why should I not upload images of data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: HI Peter, your formula works well, but in the case where I want to filter by departments, i.e. 611, 612, 613, I just get blanks.

Comment: Hi @Peter, I couldnt finish my last post, but when I filter by departments i still get no information, data type is set up as dates. What else can I do? My colum id is not a consecutive number like your table its set up by departments like 11,12,14,15,16 (it might not matter) but still no cigar

Comment: Hi @Peter I apologize, I did find your formula helpful, but it still does not throw me the result I needed. I believe I have provided enough evidence that it does not work, see my image "line chart no info for departments" I have the exact same formula you suggested, however when I want to summarize by departments the formula counts every row, including blanks or 0's which throws the values out. Sorry for the inconvenience and I am grateful for your help